# Migrating from FlinkKafkaConsumer to KafkaSource, no windows executed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have implemented `FlinkKafkaConsumer` to consume messages from a kafka-topic. The only custom setting other than "group" and "topic" is `(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")` to enable re-reading the same messages several times. It works out of the box for consuming and logic.

Now `FlinkKafkaConsumer` is **deprecated**, and I wanted to update to its successor `KafkaSource`.

Initializing `KafkaSource` with the same parameters as I do `FlinkKafkaConsumer` produces a read of the topic as expected, i can verify this by printing the stream. De-serialization and timestamps seem to work fine. However execution of windows is not done, and as such no results are produced.

I assume some default setting(s) in `KafkaSource` are different from that of `FlinkKafkaConsumer`, but I have no idea what they might be.

##### KafkaSource - **Not working**

```java
KafkaSource<TestData> source = KafkaSource.<TestData>builder()
     .setBootstrapServers(propertiesForKafka.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"))
     .setTopics(TOPIC)
     .setDeserializer(new CustomDeserializer())
     .setGroupId(GROUP_ID)
     .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
     .build();

DataStream<TestData> testDataStreamSource = env.fromSource(
     source,
     WatermarkStrategy. <
     TestData > noWatermarks(),
     "Kafka Source"
 );
```

##### Kafka consumer - **Working**

(Properties contains `group.id`,`bootstrap.servers` and `zookeeper.connect`)

```java
propertiesForKafka.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
FlinkKafkaConsumer<TestData> flinkKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(TOPIC, new CustomDeserializer(), propertiesForKafka);
DataStreamSource<TestData> testDataStreamSource = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer)
```

Both streams use the same pipeline that looks like this

```java
testDataStreamSource
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<TestData>forMonotonousTimestamps().withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) - > event.getTimestamp()))
    .keyBy(TestData::getKey)
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(3), Time.hours(1)))
    .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<TestData, TestDataOutput, String, TimeWindow>() {
            @Override
            public void process(
                ....
            });
```

Things tried

- I've tried to experiment with setting committing of offsets, but it
  has not improved the situation.
- Setting timestamps already in the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: The answer is that the KafkaSource behaves differently than FlinkKafkaConsumer in the case where the number of Kafka partitions is smaller than the parallelism of Flink's kafka source operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101290/2000823 for details.

Original answer:

The problem is almost certainly something related to the timestamps and watermarks.

To verify that timestamps and watermarks are the problem, you could do a quick experiment where you replace the 3-hour-long event time  sliding windows with short processing time tumbling windows.

In general it is preferred (but not required) to have the KafkaSource do the watermarking. Using `forMonotonousTimestamps` in a watermark generator applied after the source, as you are doing now, is a risky move. This will only work correctly if the timestamps in all of the partitions being consumed by each parallel instance of the source are processed in order. If more than one Kafka partition is assigned to any of the KafkaSource tasks, this isn't going to happen. On the other hand, if you supply the `forMonotonousTimestamps` watermarking strategy in the fromSource call (rather than `noWatermarks`), then all that will be required is that the timestamps be in order on a per-partition basis, which I imagine is the case.

As troubling as that is, it's probably not enough to explain why the windows don't produce any results. Another possible root cause is that the test data set doesn't include any events with timestamps after the first window, so that window never closes.

Do you have a sink? If not, that would explain things.

You can use the Flink dashboard to help debug this. Look to see if the watermarks are advancing in the window tasks. Turn on checkpointing, and then look to see how much state the window task has -- it should have some non-zero amount of state.

Comment: I actually add the timestamps in the stream later. I don't know if it makes any difference. Will update the inital question with an example of the usage of the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer. Didn't see it until now.

The tumbling event window does indeed execute the processing.

I have edited the timestamps to be assigned from source rather than afterwards! Thanks for the input.

The test data set does contain enough event timestamps (over 50000) that they should be executed, it works as soon as i switch to FlinkKafkaConsumer which i use to verify the test data.

I will look at the dashboard and see if i see anything!

I use a PrintSinkFunction for debugging, it seems to do the job.

Comment: Ok so i found out some things by using the gui.
The gui showed both versions of the job (KafkaSource and FlinkKafkaConsumer) working identically, and to my surprise by attaching a database, i found the output correct.

This means that it's my IDE (Intellij IDEA) that is not working the same for the two sources (not writing or executing any windows). Because doing the same thing there results in zero rows in db.

Comment: Another finding is that setting parallelism to 1 in the code makes the window commit and everything works.

Comment: In the cases where you reported it NOT WORKING, what sink were you using?

Comment: Both PrintSink and JdbcSink were not working (executing windows) with parallelism set to > 1 for kafkasource. But set to 1 it executes for both.
For KafkaConsumer any parallelism works.